# "Could" in various contexts

Tags: modal-verbs

## Scene 1 from the movie *Little Miss Sunshine*

> Richard: And how Dwayne's utilizing seven of them in his personal quest to self-fulfillment.
>
> Sheryl: Richard, please.
>
> Richard: Well, I'm just saying I've come around. I think he **could** use our support.
>
> Olive: How did it happen?
>
> Frank: How did what happen?
>
> Olive: Your accident.

## Scene 2 from The Matrix

> Morpheus: I imagine that right now, you're feeling a bit like Alice. Hmm? Tumbling down the rabbit hole?
>
> Neo: You **could** say that.
>
> Morpheus: I see it in your eyes. You have the look of a man who accepts what he sees because he is expecting to wake up. Ironically, that's not far from the truth. Do you believe in fate, Neo?
>
> Neo: No.

## Scene 3 from The Matrix Reloaded

> Morpheus: Neo, if you're out there I **could** use some help.

My best guess is that the first **could** signals a suggestion or offer, the second giving permission and the third expressing strong feelings (conditional).

Please help to explain the different usages of **could** here.

Comment: I think that *"could"* in all those examples can be interpreted as expressing a possibility. The context in Scene 3 of course signals a suggestion, but I don't think one can argue that a permission is requested or granted in Scene 2.

Comment: The context in Scene 3 definitely **doesn't** signal a suggestion. Morpheus says that for himself, not to Neo. Neo is flying to him and the keymaker. Obviously Morpheus doesn't know Neo is coming for his rescue. The answer below also precludes that possibility. @Nico

Comment: I interpreted that context as Morpheus, figuratively, asking for help to Neo. In hindsight, I would remove "obviously" from my previous comment, because it sounds patronising and that's far from my intention.

Comment: Would **request** be a better word than **suggestion** here? @Nico

Comment: It's hard to answer this in a single comment. Yes, I agree it is a request, but I also think it is expressed as a suggestion. Morpheus needs help, but instead of asking "**could** you help​​ **?**", he expresses the request as a suggestion to himself "I **could** use some help".

Comment: We're discussing *"I could use some help"* in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7227/english-language-learners). It is a common collocation/idiom. Its meaning is better explained by how it is used than by the usage of "could" as a modal verb.

Comment: At last, I saw your comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/7227/2014/5/13/17-20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In example one Richard is suggesting that providing support to Dwayne
*may* be helpful to him. It's less strong than 'he needs our support'.

On the face of it, example three is exactly the same as example one:
Morpheus is suggesting that Neo's help *might* make something easier.
It's not that simple, however, as this is a fairly common case of
understatement where Morpheus really means that he *needs* Neo's help.

Example two is a bit different as it's a stock phrase that means,
essentially, yes. In this example I think it's used to suggest that
while what Morpheus says is more or less correct, it's not the way
that Neo would have said it, or that while the overall meaning is correct, the details are wrong.

If the emphasis was on the last word in the sentence, 'you could say
*that*', it would then be a suggestion that *that* would be the best
thing to say. If it was giving permission to say something it would
most likely be something like 'you can say that' or 'you may say that'.

Comment: I can't agree more. Just one more thing, why would Morpheus want to understate here? Can you plz give me some more examples with this particular usage of "could"?

Comment: It's a long time since I've seen the movie and I'm struggling to explain why he uses that phrase. It could just be that he's the sort of person who can't admit to needing help. I think the characters motivations are outside the scope of this site anyway. I'll try to think of some more examples of that phrase in use, though. By the way, since we're discussing "could" I'll point out that we'd normally say "I couldn't agree more" rather than "can't".

Comment: Yep, you are right. I couldn't agree more if I were to give my opinion. The characters motivations are outside the scope of this site, but what we are talking about is the context here. It's totally legit to go beyond grammar or usage. The scenario related to that utterance in the movie seems to be extremely urgent. Morpheus is going to die in seconds. There is no reason for him to understate his words. Fortunately, Neo flies to him and the keymaker in time and rescue them both. You might want to search in Youtube for that specific clip.